# Is there any advice on how to tweak my code to return the correct table as a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am tyring to write a function that takes a dataframe, groups the dataframe by a column, and then orders that column by from largest to smallest using the average of a second column. I am trying to return a dataframe. I am using both seaborn and pandas.

This what I have so far

```
def table(df, columnone, columntwo):
    dfnew = df.groupby([columnone])[columntwo].nlargest()
    
    return dfnew
```

I am not very sure what I am missing or what I should be looking for. I am pretty new with python and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think your question is better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can you post some sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this:

```
def table(df, columnone, columntwo):
    return df.groupby([columnone])\
        .mean()\
        .sort_values(by=[columntwo], ascending=False)
```

Here `groupby` will create the groups, `mean` will average the values in other columns, `sort_values` will sort the resulting dataframe created after applying `groupby`.